# php: how to get a value from a nested array

Tags: php, json

I have the JSON response below using `$a=file_get_contents`, and I need to echo the value of [id] which is 2316713 in this example. When I use `echo $a["id"]` I get this output: 
"R" .
Any suggestions?

```
Response:
---------
Array
(
    [id] => 2316713
    [key] => xxxxxx
    [status] => initialising
    [sandbox] => 1
    [created_at] => 2018-02-26T23:38:52Z
    [finished_at] => 
    [source_file] => Array
        (
            [id] => 29757828
            [name] => test1.pptx
            [size] => 134718
        )
    [target_files] => Array
        (
        )
    [target_format] => png
    [credit_cost] => 1
)
```

Comment: is this code the output of `print $a`?

Comment: Yes, which is the response of API at the same time.

Comment: The response should be in json , which you need to convert back to array and display the required field

Comment: Using json_decode?

Comment: Well currently it doesn't look like JSON, it looks more like someone has done a Php print_r.  Perhaps you need to change your request to get a JSON response.

Comment: show your code and the json, instead of this diluted view.

Comment: Here is the JSON response I receive from the server using Zamzar API: http://presentationtube.com/v3/browserrecord/PPT/1_zamzar_convert.php.

Comment: that is not json, just some guy's view(transformation) of some input.

Comment: So, how can I read/get the value of [id] using this format/transformation?

Comment: We need to see your code to help. file_get_contents returns a string, so your output is confusing from what you have above.

Comment: This is the code: 
$jsondata= file_get_contents('$URL');
print_r($jsondata);

Answer (score 1):

I can mock a response and parse that:

```
<?php

$data =
[
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'cakes' => 'hot'
];

$response =
"Response:\n
---------\n" . print_r($data, true);

$foo = preg_match('/\[foo\] => (.*)/', $response, $match)
    ? $match[1]
    : null;

var_dump($foo);
```

Output:

```
string(3) "bar"
```

But if you expect JSON, perhaps you need to change your request, and handle the response differently.